# issue on macos while breaking an expression in several lines through sed

Tags: regex, sed, sh

I am cutting an expression after 135 characters and printing each line starting with + or - through the command

```
cat file1 | tr -d '\n' > file2
sed 's/\(\(.\)\{,135\}\) \([\+\-]\)/\1\n\3/g' file2 > file3
```

cat file1

```
(-128*r1*T6*y*(22*y^3 + 32*y^2*(-1 + z) + 33*y*(-1 + z)^2 + 12*(-1 + z)^3))/
  3 - (128*r1*T2*y*(11*y^3 - 2*y^2*z - 3*y*z^2 - 12*z^3))/3 +
 (128*r1*T3*z*(12*y^3 + 3*y^2*z + 2*y*z^2 - 11*z^3))/3 -
 2816*r1*T1*(y^4 + 2*y^3*(-1 + z) + 3*y^2*(-1 + z)^2 + 2*y*(-1 + z)^3 +
  (1 - z + z^2)^2) + (256*r1*T5*(11 + 11*y^4 + 14*z - 14*y^3*z - 36*z^2 +
 44*z^3 - 22*z^4 - 6*y^2*z*(-7 + 6*z) - 2*y*z*(21 - 36*z + 22*z^2)))/3 +
 (128*r1*T8*(110 + 99*y^4 - 174*z + 261*z^2 - 164*z^3 + 99*z^4 +
  2*y^3*(-82 + 81*z) + 3*y^2*(87 - 172*z + 86*z^2) +
  6*y*(-29 + 86*z - 86*z^2 + 27*z^3)))/3
```

This works on linux, however does not in mac. The error is showing is the following

```
sed: 1: "s/\(\(.\)\{,135\}\) \([ ...": RE error: invalid repetition count(s)
```

Any way out to fix this?

Comment: Try putting {1,135} instead. As per docs the second argument can be omitted and not the first. See https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-regular-expressions

Comment: with this modification it does not break the lines anymore.. however the complain is not there though.

Comment: Try `'s/\(.\{1,135\}\) \([+-]\)/\1\n\2/g'`

Comment: Now its not breaking the line!!

Answer (score 0):

BSD `sed` doesn't replace `\n` with a newline character. You can, however, embed a *literal* newline into the string:

```
$ tr -d '\n' < file1 | sed 's/\(\(.\)\{0,135\}\) \([\+\-]\)/\1\
> \3/g'
(-128*r1*T6*y*(22*y^3 + 32*y^2*(-1 + z) + 33*y*(-1 + z)^2 + 12*(-1 + z)^3))/  3 - (128*r1*T2*y*(11*y^3 - 2*y^2*z - 3*y*z^2 - 12*z^3))/3
+ (128*r1*T3*z*(12*y^3 + 3*y^2*z + 2*y*z^2 - 11*z^3))/3 - 2816*r1*T1*(y^4 + 2*y^3*(-1 + z) + 3*y^2*(-1 + z)^2 + 2*y*(-1 + z)^3 +  (1 - z
+ z^2)^2) + (256*r1*T5*(11 + 11*y^4 + 14*z - 14*y^3*z - 36*z^2 + 44*z^3 - 22*z^4 - 6*y^2*z*(-7 + 6*z) - 2*y*z*(21 - 36*z + 22*z^2)))/3
+ (128*r1*T8*(110 + 99*y^4 - 174*z + 261*z^2 - 164*z^3 + 99*z^4 +  2*y^3*(-82 + 81*z) + 3*y^2*(87 - 172*z + 86*z^2) +  6*y*(-29 + 86*z
- 86*z^2
+ 27*z^3)))/3
```

The `>` at the beginning of the second line is the secondary prompt, indicating that the single-quoted string hasn't yet been closed.

Comment: It is claiming 
    sed: 1: "s/(\(.\)\{0,135\}\) \([ ...": RE error: parentheses not balanced
and I can't compile either.

Comment: Somehow, I lost the backslash before the initial `(`; fixed now.